# Can the corruption spread underground pre hardmode?

Tags: terraria-console

Is there dirt in an underground corruption? If there is will it spread pre hardmode? If it can’t, I’ll just place sunflowers of both sides of it and dig trenches so it doesn’t reach my house

Answer (score 2):

In prehardmode, it can only spread to dirt blocks and sand blocks, unlike hardmode where it could spread through stone and mud. There is a chance that at the bottom of a corruption chasm there is a patch of corrupted dirt and flower walls, but it cannot spread.